# Loading scripts using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, external

```
$.ajax({ url: "plugin.js", dataType: 'script', cache: true, success: function() {
    alert('loaded');
}});
```

1) I can't get the script to load, probably due to incorrect path, but how do I determine the correct path? The above code is in init.js, plugin.js is also in the same folder.

2) Can I load multiple plugins at once with the same request? eg. plugin.js, anotherplugin.js?

```
root
|
|_ html > page.html
|
|_ static > js > init.js, plugin.js
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use getScript, not ajax. Ajax is for loading data, not for executing code.

If you need to load multiple files, try something like this:

```
var scripts = ['plugin.js', 'test.js'];
for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
  $.getScript(scripts[i], function() {
    alert('script loaded');
  });
}
```

Comment: From the docs: `getScript` is shorthand for `$.ajax({ url: url, dataType: 'script', success: success });`, so there's nothing wrong with using `.ajax`, it's just a bit more verbose.

Comment: I'm using .ajax specifically for asynchronous caching (cache: true).

Answer (score 3):

1) The path will be relative to the *page* it's loaded from (not the path of your init script) since that's the url the browser will be at when it executes the ajax request.

**Edit**: Based on your edit, the path to load your script from is either `/static/js/plugin.js` (if it'll be deployed at the root of your domain), or `../static/js/plugin.js` to be safe (assuming all pages that it'll be loaded from will be in `/html`).

2) No. If they're in different files, they'll need to be different requests. You could merge them into one file on the server-side though...

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the desc to show the structure, can you help find the path? Thanks!

Comment: Tried both /static/js/plugin.js and /static/js/plugin.js but it still won't load. Any other way of cross-checking?

Comment: First try loading the file directly in the browser, it should work at `http://<domain>/static/js/plugin.js`. Assuming the file is where you expect & that works, try installing [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and watch the Net panel when the ajax request is fired to see the actual URL being requested and to see what the response is...

Comment: Thank you! I didn't the the path was relative to the *page*, I'm new at jQuery and this was consuming a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

As an update, the better way to do this with jQuery 1.9.x is to use Deferreds-methods (i.e. $.when), such as follows:

```
$.when(
  $.getScript('url/lib.js'),
  $.getScript('url/lib2.js')
).done(function() {
  console.log('done');
})
```

The `.done()` callback function has a number of useful params.

Read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery [.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function, which will load the script and include it in the current document.

1) The path should be `/static/js/plugin.js`, relative to your document.

2) No. Each file is loaded by a single HTTP request.

Comment: Tried both /static/js/plugin.js and /static/js/plugin.js but it still won't load. Any other way of cross-checking the path?

Comment: Use Firefox when developing. Install Firebug (plugin) which is free. Inside that, activate all "debug panels" and place a "breakpoint" where you need to stop the javascript. Then you can mouse-over on the active variables and read their current value. Quite nice!

Answer (score 0):

I would check Firebug's *net* tab to see if it was loaded correctly, and the path it is trying to load from.

The path will be from the document where the JavaScript was included.

I also keep a config object like this (PHP in this example)

```
var config = { basePath: '<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>' };
```

Then you could do

```
var request = config.basePath + 'path/to/whatever.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'../'` to set the script path as base path. Then add the relative path for the

```
    $.getScript("../plugin.js").done(function(script, textStatus ) {
    alert("loaded:" + textStatus);
}).fail(function(script, textStatus ) {
    alert("failed: " + textStatus);
});
```